# Different response when trying to get external client IP address

Tags: asp.net, dns

I'm wondering why when using the following code:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
```

it returns the local gateway address of the server. For example, (192.168.1.1).

But when using:

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host)(0).ToString()
```

it successfully resolves the external IP address of local clients.

I've recently upgraded the gateway/firewall on the web server network, and can't figure out why the new gateway would be altering the headers in such a way.

Answer (score 0):

Those two are very different.

`HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress` Gives you the IP address of the **remote client AKA user** who has made the request to your website. Accessing this property is instant i.e. does not involve querying and resolving. This is the correct way of obtaining the user's IP address.

`System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host)(0).ToString()` Gives you the IP address of the **website host** itself, by querying your system's configured DNS server. It's *never* going to give you the IP address of the user.

If you are getting `192.168.1.1` from `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress` for all requests then it might be a router/forwarding misconfiguration.